# Escaped regular characters

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Are strings such as `"\$"` illegal? Why or why not? (Gcc and clang give a warning but treat it as if it was `"$"`) How is `\` followed by a character that, with the backslash prepended, doesn't form a reserved escape sequence supposed to behave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is explicit in a (non normative) note of the draft n1570 for C11. The 6.4.4.4 Character constants paragraph defines escape sequences as:

> escape-sequence:
>
> - simple-escape-sequence
> - octal-escape-sequence
> - hexadecimal-escape-sequence
> - universal-character-name
>
> simple-escape-sequence: one of
>
> - \' \" \? \
> - \a \b \f \n \r \t \v
>
> octal-escape-sequence:
>
> - \ octal-digit
> - \ octal-digit octal-digit
> - \ octal-digit octal-digit octal-digit
>
> hexadecimal-escape-sequence:
>
> - \x hexadecimal-digit
> - hexadecimal-escape-sequence hexadecimal-digit

All other sequences of another character following a `\` are not defined here, so the behaviour is unspecified (not undefined) by current standard

A note says:

> 77) ... **If any other character follows a backslash,
>   the result is not a token and a diagnostic is required**. See ‘‘future language directions’’ (6.11.4).

And 6.11.4 says:

> 6.11.4 Character escape sequences
>
> Lowercase letters as escape sequences are reserved for future standardization. Other
>   characters may be used in extensions.

Commonly, compilers issue the required warning but just ignore the superfluous `\`. It is fully conformant for non lowercase letters as it can be a local extension, but it could break in a future version of the C language for lower case letters because it is explicitely a *reserved feature*

Answer (score 2):

From [this escape sequence reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/escape):

> ISO C requires a diagnostic if the backslash is followed by any character not listed here.

So a compiler is required to print a message about it.

After a quick reading of the C11 specification (INCITS+ISO+IEC+9899-2011[2012], following the references in the above linked reference) I find no mention about behavior. While it could be specified somewhere else I doubt it, so the behavior for unspecified escape sequences is, well, unspecified.