# Do useless backslashs produce well-defined string constants?

Tags: c++, c, escaping, portability, string-literals

Both, C and C++, support an seemingly equivalent set of escape sequences like `\b`, `\t`, `\n`, `\"` and others starting with the backslash character (`\`). How is a backslash handled if normal character follows? As far as I remember from several compilers the escape character `\` is silently skipped. On cppreference.com, I read these articles

- [Escape sequences (C)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/escape)
- [Escape sequences (C++)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape)

I only found this note (in the C article) about orphan backslashes

> ISO C requires a diagnostic if the backslash is followed by any character not listed here: [...]

above the reference table. I had also a look an some online compilers

### [C demo](https://ideone.com/TOselY)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    printf("%d", !strcmp("\\ x", "\\ x"));
    printf("%d", !strcmp("\\ x", "\\\ x"));
    printf("%d", !strcmp("\\ x", "\\\\ x"));
    return 0;
}
```

### [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/aCwjaW)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << (string("\\ x") == "\\ x");
    cout << (string("\\ x") == "\\\ x");
    cout << (string("\\ x") == "\\\\ x");
    return 0;
}
```

Both treat `"\\ x"` and `"\\\ x"` as equivalent, (kind of) warning via syntax highlighting. IOW `"\\\ x"` has been transformed into `"\\ x"`.

Can I assume this to be defined behavior?

### Clarification (edit)

- I'm *not asking* about obviously invalid string literals like `"\"`.
- I'm *aware* that an orphan backslash is somewhat problematic.
- I want to know if the result, the constant built by the compiler, is *defined*.

---

Edit #2: Focus even more on constant being generated (and portability).

Comment: Both gcc and g++ complain: >warning: unknown escape sequence: '\040'

Comment: @OlafDietsche ... you mean for C++ code as well? And is `' '` put into the constant?

Comment: Yes, both complain about `\<blank>`.

Comment: @Wolf be careful, diagnostic in both doesn't means the same in that case. For C it is a diagnostic for an invalid program, for C++ that the sequence is not defined by this implementation but the program is valid (other compiler may define that sequence).

Comment: I'm definitely be careful about this, thanks so far. Maybe it's a portability issue first of all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escaped regular characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40863676/escaped-regular-characters) The answer from @serge states: "It is fully conformant for non lowercase letters".

Comment: @KamilCuk I have to admit that I'm coming from C++, assuming string literals are traditionally handles equally, I added the C tag as well. Now I'm surprised that there *is* a difference. It's also time-dependent C17 is a fix to C11 after the other question was asked.

Comment: @Wolf Then you discovered that C++ is not just a superset of C... They are different in many details.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I know that this superset property was intended to allow migration/transition, but the standardization process is decoupled now. On the other hand, both languages keep inspiring each other see for example [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). Given the overwhelming similarities, it should be permissible to ask about the distinguishing details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer is no. It is an invalid C program and *unspecified behavior* C++ one.

### **C Standard**

says it is syntactically wrong (emphasize is mine), it does not produce a valid token, thus the program is invalid:

> **5.2.1 Character sets**
>
> **2/** In a character constant or string literal, members of the execution character set shall be represented by corresponding members of the source character set or by escape sequences consisting of the backslash \ followed by one or more characters.
>
> **6.4.4.4 Character constants**
>
> **3/**
>   The single-quote ', the double-quote ", the question-mark ?, the backslash \, and arbitrary integer values are representable according to the following table of escape sequences:
>
> - single quote ' `\'`
> - double quote " `\"`
> - question mark ? `\?`
> - backslash \ `\\`
> - octal character `\octal digits`
> - hexadecimal character `\xhexadecimal digits`
>
> **8/** In addition, characters not in the basic character set are representable by universal
>   character names and certain nongraphic characters are representable by escape sequences
>   consisting of the backslash \ followed by a lowercase letter: \a, \b, \f, \n, \r, \t, and \v. Note : **If any other character follows a backslash, the result is not a token and a diagnostic is required**.

### **C++ standard**

says differently (emphasize is mine):

> **5.13.3 Character literals**
>
> **7/** Certain non-graphic characters, the single quote ’, the double quote ", the question mark ?,25 and the backslash \, can be represented according to Table 8. The double quote " and the question mark ?, can be represented as themselves or by the escape sequences \" and \? respectively, but the single quote ’ and the backslash \ shall be represented by the escape sequences \’ and \ respectively. **Escape sequences in which the character following the backslash is not listed in Table 8 are conditionally-supported, with implementation-defined semantics**. An escape sequence specifies a single character.

Thus for C++, you need to have a look at your compiler manual for the semantic, but the program is syntactically valid.

Comment: Well, that's my point *`a diagnostic is required`* does not mean that the outcome has to be undefined.

Comment: Such an escape sequence is not permitted by syntax, thus the program is invalid.

Comment: It really seems to be different in C and C++. Not being a token - said by the C std - for the whole "literal" containing an invalid escape sequence can be clearly read as: this is an error (a lexical one). For C++ it seems to be permitted under some circumstances.

Comment: [this defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_324.htm) comes very close with the question `What in the formal content of the standard says that if any other character follows a backslash, there should be a diagnostic? Does such a case causes undefined behaviour?`. Could it be that  "is not a token" means it is not a token by itself (ex. `\i` is not a variable `i`), but can be a part of other token (ex. `'\i'` is a character constant)?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès *`Answer is no.`* is clear *to me* but without the context (requires reading the question) it's not helpful for future readers. I'd suggest adding something like *You should be prepared for undefined behavior.*

Comment: @Wolf, this is not *undefined behavior* (which as a well defined semantic), it is (1) invalid program for C, (2) *unspecified-behavior* for C++

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I see, but *unspecified* means not portable, right?

Comment: @Wolf Well hard to say exactly we would need to define what portable means... But ok.

Comment: "conditionally-supported, with implementation-defined semantics" is not "unspecified".

Answer (score 3):

You need to compile with a conforming C compiler. Various online compilers tend to use gcc which is by default set to "lax non-standard mode", aka GNU C. This may or may not enable some non-standard escape sequences, but it also won't produce compiler *errors* even when you violate the C language - you might get away with a "warning", but that doesn't make the code valid C.

If you tell gcc to behave as a conforming C compiler with `-std=c17 -pedantic-errors`, you get this error:

> `error: unknown escape sequence: '\040'`

040 is octal for 32 which is the ASCII code for `' '`. (For some reason gcc uses octal notation for escape sequences internally, might be because \0 is octal, I don't know why.)

Comment: Is this (raise an error) part of some C++ or C standard?

Comment: @Wolf `\ ` is not a valid escape sequence listed in C 6.4.4.4 so yes it's a syntax error.

Comment: Isn't it an [extension](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.11.4)? and [footnote 56](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#note65)

Comment: I haven't looked in any standard, but "requires a diagnostic" doesn't mean raise an error, just put out some message.

Comment: "Requires a diagnostic" means compilation continues but maybe the resulting object code is implementation defined.

Comment: @OlafDietsche yes, but the C standard says that the result is not a token, thus the program is invalid and a diagnostic message must be produced.